# What is the connection between geometry of physical space and Hilbert space?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, geometry, topology

In Quantum Mechanis (QM), the dynamical variables are the (quantized) coordinates $x_j$ and their canonical conjugate $p_j = -i\partial_j$  with the commutation relation $[x_j,p_k]=i\delta_{jk}$ acting as operators on the quantum state space.

What exactly happens to that state space when we change the underlying geometry or topology of "physical" space - the (spacetime) manifold that serves as the background for the quantum system? How does this change in geometry/topology reflect on the Hilbert space?

In Quantum Field Theory (QFT), the dynamical objects are the (quantized) fields $\phi (x^\mu)$ and the coordinates $x_i$ are demoted to mere labels. What happens in this case? How does a change in geometry/topology alter the resulting Fock space?

I am new to this area, so what I need would be a basic explanation (for QM and QFT) how to make the connection between the two concepts geometry/topology of physical space and resulting properties of the quantum state space - if such a wish makes sense at all.

Comment: To be precise - with "geometry/topology of physical space" you mean the structure of the classical *phase space*, which in turn is the cotangent bundle of the configuration space (any manifold, basically) charted by the coordinates $x_j$? And we are doing some variant of geometric quantization? (In the context of structure of the phase space, one must recall [Darboux' theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem), heuristically indicating that no "local" effects can be seen since, locally, there is just one symplectic geometry)

Comment: changing coordinates doesn't change the geometry/topology of a manifold, so it is not entirely clear to me what you're asking here. As to whether there are changes between configuration spaces of different dimensions then the answer is that in general there is no difference because of von Neumann's uniqueness theorem.

Comment: With "physical space" I just mean the (spacetime) manifold in which I place my quantum system. I guess one would call it semi-classical as it is QM/QFT on a fixed background. For instance, I could analyse a particle in a curved space. How would such a change of geometry affect the quantum state space?

Comment: @ACuriousMind By changing the physical space, for example in the case of a scalar, he means changing $g_{\mu\nu}$ in $\mathcal L \sim g_{\mu\nu}\partial_\mu \phi \partial_\nu \phi + \dots$ That is, the underlying spacetime, or in string theoretic language, the target space.

Comment: Yes, exactly! The underlying spacetime (or in the non-relativistic case just the space, e.g. an electron confined to a curved surface). What (if any) happens to the Hilbert/Fock space? Do the quantum states or operators change?

Comment: @JamalS: Correct me if I'm wrong, but we have no full quantum theory that would quantize on a full general relativity spacetime, have we? I see how string theory might answer this, but this question then is not really about the quantization procedure we have in QM and QFT, usually.

Comment: OP, are you perhaps looking for [QFT in curved spacetime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_field_theory_in_curved_spacetime)?

Comment: @ACuriousMind: It doesnt necessarily have to be relativistic. Let us consider the case of an electron confined to a curved surface. Does the geometry of the background have any consequences for the state space?

Comment: @ACuriousMind I wasn't suggesting that string theory may answer this anyway, I just used it to form the question in other words. And yes, there is no full way.

Comment: @quantumorsch : please see ***a simple situation*** and you will understand. Let's say for simplicity that we work in one dimension. Then the population inside a Hilbert space are functions $\psi(x)$. Now, let's pass to another configuration space where $y = ax$, with $a=$ some constant. In the functions $\psi (x)$ we have to introduce the transformation $x = y/a$. In all we get the functions $\psi(y/a)$. Our new operators $x$ and $p$ will be now $y$ and $-i \hbar \frac {∂}{∂y} = -i \frac {\hbar}{a} \frac {∂}{∂x} $. (I continue)

Comment: @quantumorsch Then, what happens when we calculate, say $\langle p \rangle$? We do $\frac {1}{a} \int \psi^*(y/a) \frac {∂\psi (y/a)}{∂y} \  dy$. Do this calculus! You'll get in the end $\frac {1}{a}\int \psi^*(x) \frac {∂\psi (x)}{∂x} dx$. In all you get that $\langle p \rangle$ is $a$ times smaller than in the former geometry because $y$ is $a$ times bigger. Don't forget that $p = mv$, so, if you use for distance a unit $a$ times bigger, the value of the velocity is $a$ times smaller.

Comment: it seems like this question could be interpreted as asking about how QM meshes with GR which is an open area of research..... its an open question for decades how to reconcile the two.

Comment: @vzn the questioner didn't ask *big philosophy*, he wanted to be given some simple notion of what happens. I gave him.

Comment: lol QM meshing with GR is not _philosophy_... its a deep empirical question at the heart of applied physics affecting cosmology, big bang, expansion of universe, black holes, etc... ps it is nearly a question that even Einstein may have worked on some...

Comment: a similar question but on the GR space : [The Physical Basis of Our Assumptions about Physical Space](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/235947/the-physical-basis-of-our-assumptions-about-physical-space). While the objects seem different , their relation is similar and the 2 topics may share their approachs on the connectors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP [comments](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/164378/what-is-the-connection-between-geometry-of-physical-space-and-hilbert-space#comment346272_164378) as an example of what the question is about:

> Let us consider the case of an electron confined to a curved surface. Does the geometry of the background have any consequences for the state space?

A simple answer can be given for ordinary QM: A (scalar, i.e. spin-0) particle moving in one-dimension has state space $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, a particle in three dimensions has state space $L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$. The state space of a particle moving on a submanifold $\mathcal{M} \subset \mathbb{R}^3$, e.g. a particle moving on any smooth surface, is then by analogy simply $L^2(\mathcal{M})$ i.e. the functions whose square-integral over $\mathcal{M}$ exists.

Note that Fourier (i.e. relating the position and momentum representations) transforms on manifolds that are not $\mathbb{R}^n$ are somewhat complicated, cf. [this math.SE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/13902).

Comment: OK, thank you! So to keep it simple: an electron confined to 1D (thin wire) is described by exactly the same state space for every possible bending of the wire (since the functions on it stay the same) - no quantum states change at all? No shift in energy levels or anything like that?

Comment: @quantumorsch: I believe that is the case - one dimension is one dimension, and ordinary QM has no way to "see" the curvature.

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted to know! The Hilbert space cannot see the curvature/geometry/topology of the underlying manifold (background space). I find it quite remarkable that all those systems in arbitrarily complicated geometries (but with the same dimension) are exactly the same and there are no consequences for the quantum states and operators at all!

Comment: @quantumorsch: The spacetime (or space) is not really the "underlying manifold" of the Hilbert space of a quantum system. The Hilbert space of the quantum version of a classical system is obtained from the classical *phase space* of the system, not the spacetime it lives in.

Comment: Sure, thanks. Of course the wave function lives on configuration/phase space, not space - but the system itself does. So I still find it quite confusing that a change in the geometry of that space does not affect quantum states...

Comment: @quantumorsch: It's not that easy, see the link to QFT in curved spacetime I commented on your question. We don't have a full quantum theory living on a full GR spacetime. Also, that the state spaces are the same does not mean that the *states* are the same. The states for a particle confined to a bent line are not the same states as those for a particle on a straight lines, their state spaces are naturally *isomorphic* as they are both $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, they are not literally *the same*.

Comment: Oh, so it *does* change the quantum states! That is what I would naively expect. I accepted your answer, but unfortunately I am still not satisfied...

Answer (score 0):

Comments to the question (v3):

1. The possible quantum states depend on the topology of spacetime. For instance, the momentum in the extra (fifth) direction of a 5-dimensional [Kaluza-Klein theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaluza%E2%80%93Klein_theory) is quantized/discrete variable if the extra (fifth) dimension is a compact circle $S^1$, but a continuous variable if the extra (fifth) dimension instead is a non-compact real line $\mathbb{R}$.
2. Given a classical system with certain geometric data, say, a Hamiltonian system defined on a symplectic manifold $(M,\omega)$, it is a huge research area in physics to try to device a general recipe of how to [quantize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantization_%28physics%29) the theory, and determine the corresponding Hilbert space of physical states and observables. See e.g. the topic of *geometric quantization,* cf. Refs. 1-3.

References:

1. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_quantization).
2. [nLab](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/geometric+quantization).
3. [John Baez](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/quantization.html).